# What is the best practice in writing an Azure Function App that talks to a PostgreSQL database using the Python runtime?

Tags: python, azure-functions

How do I handle the database connection? Do I connect at the beginning of main and disconnect before I return the HttpResponse? Is this ok?

- Is there any connection pooling?
- Do Azure functions for Python have any "before"/"after" events that I could use to connect/disconnect from the database?

Answer (score -1):

Is it certain that you need to use Postgres or could you look at something like [Amazon Aurora Serverless](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/aurora/serverless/) or some other data store that has an HTTP API?

The challenge with using a pooled model with serverless compute is that the code running serverlessly is intended to be stateless outside the execution context of the function and there's limited opportunity to maintain a shared connection pool of a few dozen connections when there could be orders of magnitude higher concurrent executions of your function.

Comment: I'd need too keep this within Azure. So any idea what would be the equivalent of Amazon Aurora for Azure?

Comment: I've no familiarity with using it first hand, but my understanding is that CosmosDB supports HTTP querying. Perhaps [this blog post/series](https://medium.com/microsoftazure/azure-cosmos-db-functions-cookbook-http-querying-4afc5ed445d7) could be helpful.

Comment: I’ve used CosmosDB before on previous project and no more. It’s really awful and frustrating. This time I need a proper SQL database.